# Can I use Regular expression in svndumpfilter include statement?

Tags: svn, sed, dump, svnadmin, svndumpfilter

I need to export data from svn (server on Windows), but i don't want to include root directory.
Example:

```
svn
-project1
--trunk
--branches
-project2
--trunk
--branches
--onemorefolder
```

I want to include to project1.dump folders: trunk and branches (not project1)
I use:

```
 svnadmin dump /svn/ | svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs /project1/trunk /project1/branches | sed "s/Node-path:[ ]project1\//Node-path: /g" -b | sed "s/Node-copyfrom-path:[ ]project1\//Node-copyfrom-path: /g" -b > project1.dump
```

But I want to automate this process and created bat file:

```
call svnadmin dump /svn/iss/ -r %2:%3 | svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs /%1/trunk /%1/branches | sed "s/Node-path:[ ]%1\//Node-path: /g" -b | sed "s/Node-copyfrom-path:[ ]%1\//Node-copyfrom-path: /g" -b > %4
```

But it works only with structure where are trunk and branches folders.
How can i include all folders from my root folder and exclude this root folder?
Can I use regex in include statement?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you could do both the `sed` commands as one:

Instead of

```
sed "s/Node-path:[ ]%1\//Node-path: /g" -b | \
sed "s/Node-copyfrom-path:[ ]%1\//Node-copyfrom-path: /g" -b
```

you could do

```
sed "s/Node-\(copyfrom-\|\)path:[ ]%1\//Node-\1path: /g" -b
```

which uses the backreference `\1` in the pattern to match `Node-path` or `Node-copyfrom-path`.

For all subfolders of root, excluding the root folder itself, maybe you can try using `find <ROOTFOLDER> -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` which finds all subdirectories not including the root itself.

Perhaps something like (untested):

```
call svnadmin dump /svn/iss/ -r %2:%3  | \                   # keep same
svndumpfilter include --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs \
    `find %1 -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` | \             # used find
sed "s/Node-\(copyfrom-|\)path:[ ]%1\//Node-\1path: /g" -b \ # combined line
> %4
```

Comment: (try individual bits separately to see that they all function as you expect)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But find does not work for me. It throws an error that -t is not recognized parameter for svndumpfilter.

Comment: hmm, but we haven't used a `-t` anywhere... is the output of the `find` bit on its own what you expect? Try `find %1 -type d -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '"%p "'` which prints all the matches on one line, space-separated, with `"` around in case of spaces in the file names.