# Make lowercase path and includes in SVN dump

Tags: svn, sed, lowercase, svndump, svndumpfilter

I have a C++ project library and I am preparing port from Windows to Linux. In the same time I need to reorganize the repository via svn dump.

I would like to make all filenames and directories lowercase in the svn dump using the SED and then recreate the SVN repository again.

Maybe I could make all #include "something.h" lowercase too using svn dump and SED, but I should ignore the checksum in that case. Anyway I could compare the result of new repository and old repository by some case insensitive directory comparing tool.

How should I proccess svn dump using SED to make all filenames and directories (and includes) lowercase?

I expect that it should be something like this [Can I use Regular expression in svndumpfilter include statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667116/can-i-use-regular-expression-in-svndumpfilter-include-statement), but I don't really understand the SED and regular expression.

The dump need to be changed from

```
....
Node-path: trunk/Something/Anything.cpp
Node-action: add
Node-kind: dir
Prop-content-length: 10
Content-length: 10
PROPS-END
...
```

to

```
...
Node-path: trunk/something/anything.cpp
Node-action: add
Node-kind: dir
Prop-content-length: 10
Content-length: 10
PROPS-END
...
```

There are also properties Node-copyfrom-path, which need to be changed too.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output for the same, to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed the job using SED. The following example is for trunk only:

```
sed -b -e "s#^\(Node.*path\): \(trunk/.*\)$#\1: \L\2#" repo.dump > repolower.dump
```